# how to import own modules in Python?

Tags: python, import, module

I have a main.py file and I need to import the database tables that are in "entity / models.py". How do I do ?
I use linux and I don't want to add models.py to sys.path, I want models.py to be visible only in this project. I also don't want to create symbolic links because in my opinion it's the same thing as putting models.py inside the app itself.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the directory into a package with a `__init__.py` file. Then as usual you can import the module from the package as in:

```
from entity.models import func
```

The `__init__.py` file can just be an empty file. Just its existence will treat the directory as a package.

Hope this answer helps.